# 1822, "Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql

У меня есть 3 таблицы, пользователи, фотографии и аватары (фото пользователя, которое в данный момент отображено другому пользователю). Когда пользователь удаляется, все его фотографии и и аватары, которые показаны другим пользователям так же удаляются. Но у меня не получается создать таблицу, что я делаю не так?

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
goal VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
dob DATE DEFAULT NULL,
country VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
city VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL)""")

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS photos(
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
photo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
KEY (id),
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, photo),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)""")

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS avatars (
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
user_id INTEGER, 
avatar VARCHAR(255),
shower_id INTEGER, 
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
FOREIGN KEY (avatar) REFERENCES photos (photo) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (shower_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)""")
```

Ошибка:

```
1822, "Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'avatars_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'photos'")
```

Версия:

```
mysqlsh.exe --version
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\mysqlsh.exe   Ver 8.0.19 for Win64 on x86_64 - for MySQL 8.0.19 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))
```

Comment: Зачем в таблице users поле user_id если есть инкремент id?? Уберите это поле и в ключе id поставьте. `FOREIGN KEY (avatar) REFERENCES photos (photo)` - когда это связи стали делать через картинки? Делайте через те же id

Comment: Это для удобства. user_id я получаю от API другого сервера.

Comment: Тогда зачем вам id? глупость, честно говоря... Сделайте привязку к photos через id или добавьте на photos.photo индекс

Comment: Как пример, что бы не вводить длинные айдишники от API при манипуляциями с данными. 
А как добавить на photos.photois. индекс?  Я Честно говоря не такой спец.

Comment: Вы уверены что вам ввобще нужна таблица avatars? Насколько я понял, таблица photos это абсолютно все "фото", в т.ч. и аватары - добавьте колонку `is_avatar tinyint default 0` и просто делайте is_avatar 1 если текущее фото аватар чей-то, а то у вас даже в таблице avatars два ключа на одно поле? Во-первых, так не делается (не у вашем случае), во-вторых, вам, по факту, не нужна эта таблица

Comment: Если user_id это какой-то индекс юзера выдаваемый api то так и назовите поле - user_key, api_key, api_user_id, но не user_id

Comment: Я не могу совместить avatars и photos, как мне кажется, т.к. каждому пользователю отображается разный аватар, а не всем одинаковый. 
Это сделано для того, что бы после обновления страницы пользователь не начинал листать  фотографии сначала. Более того, 1 пользователь может видеть профиль другого пользователя несколько раз ,и каждый раз там будет другой аватар (в зависимости от того, сколько фотографий наблюдающий пользователь пролистает у отображаемого пользователя). 
Скажите главное, как проиндесировать )

Спасибо про замечание об айдишнике пользователя

Answer (score -1):

Согласно этому ответу [ответу](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/268894/208647), здесь нужно добавить строчку `KEY (photo)` в таблице `photos`, что бы проиндексировать ключ, на который ссылаются. Всятаблица будет выглядеть так:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS photos(
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
photo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
KEY (id),
KEY (photo),
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, photo),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)""")
```